# Property initialized in constructor with destructuring, but got the error that is not initialized

Tags: typescript

I encountered the following TypeScript error: 'Property 'step' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.' However, I initialized the 'step' property in the constructor using destructuring. I'm curious why TypeScript is unable to recognize this. Here's the code snippet:

```
class Watcher{    
    step: number;
    constructor(config: { step: number }) {
        const { step } = config
        console.log(step)//1
    }
}

const w = new Watcher({ step: 1 })
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDqYBdgAsCmAnA3tH0BQu0ECqADgFzQB2ArgLYBGGA3AbsAPZXHo3AId0ACk5UAZgEsA5pWzEylWowzQAvgEpomNoRyjiWoiVJroAXmijJUnbv0cQqAHQgOUofNLrbqvL7z6CNAA7ubUqKHwSGjCcsaUAIxqmgD0KdAJQA)

Comment: You didn't initialize the `step` property of `w`, though (try `console.log(w.step)` after the last line of your example; it's `undefined`, not `1`).  Inside the constructor, `step` is just a local variable. You need to assign to `this.step`, not `step`.  If you must use destructuring it would look like [this](https://tsplay.dev/N9a1JN), although I doubt that's worth it.  See the linked q/a for more information.